# How to rerun filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this HTML, I cannot change it:

```
<div>How much is 100 * X {{100 | myFilter}}</div>
```

This is the Filter:

```
X=3
app.filter(function(){
   return function(val){
       return val*X
   })
})
```

Now I want to Change X:

```
X=5
```

And I want the HTML to rerun this filter and update all the values that affected by this filter and update the value

X is only defined as global JavaScript var. not in the HTML. I want that if the X value changes it will update any filter that depends on it.

Comment: Asking people not to write new answers after you have found the answer is not in the spirit of _Stack Overflow_. Someone may show another way to solve the problem, which may be preferable to you (and so you change your mind about which answer to accept) or is more helpful to someone else than your answer. More the merrier! The only time a question will stop accepting answers is if it is put on hold (e.g. because it is too broad or it is a duplicate of something else).

Comment: Sorry, I just dont want to waste anyone time. And If I success, I want other to know. I am editing it

Comment: No problem. If you want people to know you've solved it before you get a chance to add an answer, you can always add a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer.  To who else need it. All what I have to do is to make the filter rerun on every digest cycle::

```
      filter.$stateful = true;
```

Then. after changing X, I can simply run the digest cycle using $apply or $digest.

JSFiddle that demonstrate stateful filters:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MRiGzYgXTmLLgrH9FnB1?p=preview

Comment: Shouldn't it always run as long as the input changes and one-time-binding isn't used?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then you want to Change/Input value of X and result should be X * 100 in html. Here I have created small [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amighty/4znvj8x3/). See if it helps you.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Input: <input ng-model="X">
  <div>How much is 100 * {{X}} = {{X | myFilter}}</div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('myFilter',function(){
   return function(val){
       return 100 * val; 
   }
})

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {  
    $scope.X = 3;    
}
]);
```

Updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amighty/4znvj8x3/73/) with stateful filter, external function.

```
<div id="appid" ng-app="myApp">  
<div>How much is 100 * <span id="spX">X</span> {{100 | myFilter}}</div>  
</div>
<button onclick="changeX()">
Change
</button>

var X = 3;
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('myFilter',function(){
    function filter(val) {
      return val * X; 
  }
   filter.$stateful = true;
   return filter;
})
document.getElementById("spX").innerText = X;

function changeX(){
  X = 5;
  document.getElementById("spX").innerText = X;
  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("appid")).scope();
  scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: no. X is only defined as global jacascript var. not in the html. i want that if the X value changes it will update any filter that depends on it.

Comment: You are welcome. I just created demo to use stateful filter so that it helps someone.