# How to call angularjs function while adding data to a json array?

Tags: angularjs

As I have mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285387/how-to-call-a-function-filter-in-an-attribute-of-an-angularjs-element), I have a function that returns a different text based on an input.

This is working fine when I use it in static text areas, like below:

```
<td>{{('input_text'|fnName:dataObject:'query_param')}}</td>
```

How can I call this function while I am assigning data to a json object? Originally the `input_text` is added to the json, but I need to run a lookup and replace the text.

EDIT: The json object is assigned to a dropdown, but I doubt if I will be able to call my function in the dropdown attributes.

p.s. The content in `dataObject` could change while using the application; so the function should be invoked with the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the filter's `$stateful` property to true.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35563980/4028303

This should make the filter re-run upon digest cycles, even if the left-side data being passed in hasn't changed.